# List.ConvertAll and exception

Tags: c#, exception, list

if ConvertAll throw an exception on one element, can i just skip this element and continue to the next element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The exception will need to be handled somewhere. If you expect exceptions to happen in the converter (and this is OK for the application), you must have a try-catch within the converter (the following code sample will return `null` for failed conversions):

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "1", "2", "three", "4" };

List<int?> converted = input.ConvertAll(s =>
{
    int? result = null;
    try
    {
        result = int.Parse(s);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    return result;
});
```

(yes, I know I should have used `int.TryParse`, but that would not throw an exception...)

However, eating exceptions like that always gives the smell of a workaround, and is nothing I would like to have in my code.

Comment: then the null will be put in to the converted list? no way to skip the failed one?

Comment: You could always use the `Where` method to filter the `null` values later.

Comment: @Benny; no, you can't get away with it from the start; the converter code must return a value. However, you can use the suggestion by @Samir and filter the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to skip the throwing element entirely `ConvertAll` will not result for you, however you can implement a helper method for "robust enumeration". Something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, -5 };
    Converter<int, string> converter = x =>
    {
        if (x < 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        return x.ToString();
    };

    // This code would throw
    //var result1 = integers.ConvertAll(converter).ToArray();
    //Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result1));

    // This code ignores -5 element
    var result2 = RobustEnumerating(integers, converter).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result2));
}

public static IEnumerable<K> RobustEnumerating<T, K>(IEnumerable<T> input,
    Converter<T, K> converter)
{
    List<K> results = new List<K>();
    foreach (T item in input)
    {
        try
        {
            results.Add(converter(item));
        }
        catch { continue; }
    }
    return results;
}
```

I would only do this if returning `null` or other unique value for failed conversions and then filtering the result to exclude those values is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

It may be simplest to combine, reverse, and shorten the answers given by Fredrik and Samir. Apply a Where first, then ConvertAll:

```
List<UnconvertedType> unconverted;

// do something to populate unconverted

List<ConvertedType> converted = unconverted.
    Where(ut => ut != null).
    ToList().
    ConvertAll<ConvertedType>(ut => ut as ConvertedType);
```

This way you can remove any exceptions before they get considered and can remove the try/catch block.